# Deep Merging two javascript objects lodash/vanilla

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to merge two Objects with containing objects..which contain an array of object..you got the idea. But, my code just not producing the desired result, and I can't understand why..probably because I just starting using lodash and I missing something obvious

Here are two objects which I want to merge

```
 var original = { 
    a: "bbbb", 
    Id: 1, 
    b: { 
        a: "bbb", 
        Id: 2 
    }, 
    c: "aaa",
    d: [
        { 
            a: "bbbb", 
            Id: 1, 
            b: { 
                a: "bbb", 
                Id: 2 
            }, 
            c: "aaa"
        },
        { 
            a: "bbbb", 
            Id: 2, 
            b: { 
                a: "bbb", 
                Id: 3 
            }, 
            c: "aaa" 
        }
    ] 
};

var source = { 
    a: "aaa", 
    Id: 1, 
    b: { 
        a: "aaa", 
        Id: 2 
    }, 
    c: null, 
    d: [
        { 
            a: "aaa", 
            Id: 1, 
            b: { 
                a: "aaa", 
                Id: 2 
            }, 
            c: null
        },
        { 
            a: "aaa", 
            Id: 2, 
            b: { 
                a: "aaa", 
                Id: 3 
            }, 
            c: null 
        }
    ] 
};
```

The result object should contain only "aaa" as values and no nulls.(take value from "source", unless it null and don't copy just copy arrays,but rather merge objects inside of them..) My code merges the objects just fine...but, it fails to produce correct result when it gets to the array of objects

The result should be:

```
{"a":"aaa",
 "Id":1,
 "b":
    {
     "a":"aaa",
     "Id":2
    },
    "c":"aaa",
   "d":
     [
      {
       "a":"aaa",
       "Id":1,
        "b":
         {
         "a":"aaa",
         "Id":2
         },
        "c":"aaa"
     },
```

{
           "a":"aaa",
           "Id":2,
            "b":
             {
             "a":"aaa",
             "Id":3
             },
            "c":"aaa"
         }
]}

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/yodfcn6e/

thank you!

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: How do you want the arrays to be merged? Are you assuming that the arrays will have the same length and you want to merge entries pairwise?

Comment: I edited your code to be readable. Can you add the desired result in the same format? Still unsure whether my fiddle answers what you want.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I added the desired result

Comment: Based on what you've said I think this is the result you want: https://jsfiddle.net/ug46ycba/1/

Comment: I realize I forgot to save my fiddle before sending it the first time. Let me know if this is correct for you https://jsfiddle.net/ug46ycba/1/

Comment: You got most of the values right, but the result has "c:null",but it should have "c:aaa"

Comment: Hrmm ya, because it prefers to overwrite any property using the source value. If you want you can just skip overwriting with`null` values though since they aren't useful. Would do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ug46ycba/2/

Comment: is result a new object? if not what is the source and what the target?

Comment: Sorry, but there is still nulls in the result object :) Open up the array (property "d")... {a: "aaa", Id: 1, b: {…}, c: null}

Comment: Nina Scholz, the "original " variable should be updated by "source" variable

Comment: Yeah, you would have to run the same function over each sub object. It's a bit recursive, but I'll show you.

Comment: i see only original and source. what is target?

Comment: Is the result stated in the question correct? Shouldn't the array contain two items?

Comment: The mistakes are corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the keys of the object and update only if the target has `null` values.

```js
function update(source, target) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(function (k) {
        if (target[k] === null) {
            target[k] = source[k];
            return;
        }
        if (source[k] && typeof source[k] === 'object') {
            update(source[k], target[k]);
        }
    });
}

var source = { a: "bbbb", Id: 1, b: { a: "bbb", Id: 2 }, c: "aaa", d: [{ a: "bbbb", Id: 1, b: { a: "bbb", Id: 2 }, c: "aaa" }, { a: "bbbb", Id: 2, b: { a: "bbb", Id: 3 }, c: "aaa" }] },
    target = { a: "aaa", Id: 1, b: { a: "aaa", Id: 2 }, c: null, d: [{ a: "aaa", Id: 1, b: { a: "aaa", Id: 2 }, c: null }, { a: "aaa", Id: 2, b: { a: "aaa", Id: 3 }, c: null }] };

update(source, target);

console.log(target);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```